# How we can categorize the testcase to be executed in the user defined order in robotframework?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, robotframework, test-suite

For example consider the below is the folder structure for my project.

[image]

Now I want my testcase to be executed in below order.

```
TC_101.ABC.robot
TC_201.ABC.robot
TC_301.ABC.robot
TC_102.ABC.robot
TC_103.ABC.robot
TC_203.ABC.robot
TC_202.ABC.robot
```

How this can be achieved in robotframework? Is there something like testng feature in robotframework using which we can manage the order in which our suites to be executed?

Comment: Why do you want to execute the tests in a specific order? Ideally tests are implemented to be independent of each other so that the order they are run in doesn't matter.

Comment: As for your question, I found [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/35306/how-to-run-robotframework-test-cases-in-a-particular-order-from-different-suites).

Comment: And the documentation here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My tests are independent of each other, I want to run the tests in modulewise the order that I set, so that it saves quality, as after completing the one test, it does not have to navigate to different module, so better completes one sets of testcase and then to next and so on, it can happen if I set them in my own order

Comment: I wanted to avoid using prefix solution that is mentioned, today if we have file like 01__my_suite.html and 02__another_suite.html, tomorrow I might need to create file which should be placed before this two or between the two, instead at then end, So I need to keep on updating file name to make it use friendly as I can't have 02__my_suite.html  and 02__another_suite.html with same prefix @Code-Apprentice

Comment: "as after completing the one test, it does not have to navigate to different module" So this sounds like the tests are dependent on each other. By this I mean that one tests depends on another test already navigating to a certain page before it can do its work. This seems reasonable since as you say it takes time if each test has to navigate through the exact same pages.

Comment: I'm not familar with Robot Framework. I just found the suggested solution from googling. I don't see any other solution yet.

Comment: "as after completing the one test, it does not have to navigate to different module"  I meant to say that suppose there are ten suites dependent on module1, ten suites dependent on module2, likewise so I want all suites of module1 to be executed before going to next suite of module2. As we are not login and logout all the time, if the session is there then it will be execute the next suite.

Answer (score 2):

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order Please refer this link, it executes in alphabetical order or you can prefix a number with two underscore (01__TC_Suite1.robot)

But if you don't want to change anything in the file, please use command line to execute as per your order. Below is the sample screenshot as per your file and i executed the below command in cmd prompt

[image]

```
robot TestSuite1\TC_101_Catenate.robot TestSuite2\TC_102_MergeLsit.robot TestSuite1\TC_103_DateTime.robot TestSuite2\TC_104_SplitLine.robot
```

The above command can be split into multiple line as well, if required

Please find the output and see the first line, order of execution as per given in command line

[image]